# How to find the x-intercept of Weibull distribution

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-regression, probability-distribution, weibull

I am trying to write a code to plot Weibull probability. I want to find the scale parameter which is the x-intercept where the fitted line intersects with probability = 63.2%. Also the slope is very high which might be unusual. Is it a problem with the dataset or I am plotting the whole Weibull probability distribution wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the parameters
n = 8  # Sample size
i = np.arange(1, n + 1)  # Rank of observations
E = np.array([208.9, 209.0, 209.2, 209.3, 209.6, 209.8, 209.9, 210])  # Electric breakdown strength 

# Calculate the cumulative breakdown efficiency by the given formula
p = (i - 0.5) / (n + 0.25)

# variables
x_data = np.log(E)
y_data = np.log(-np.log(1 - p))

# Fit a linear regression to estimate the parameters of the Weibull distribution
slope, intercept = np.polyfit(x_data, y_data, 1)

# Calculate the shape parameter
shape = slope  

# scale parameter is the x-intercept where the fitted line intersects with p = 63.2%. How to get that?

# Generate points for the Weibull distribution
x = np.linspace(min(x_data), max(y_data), 100)
y = slope * x + intercept

# Plot the Weibull distribution
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o')
plt.plot(x, y, label='Linear fit')
plt.xlabel('ln (E)')
plt.ylabel('Probability of failure :ln(-ln(1 - p))')
plt.title('Weibull Plot')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

print("Shape parameter:", slope)
# print("Scale parameter:", ?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDF of the Weibull distribution is `F=1-exp(-(x/L)**k)` where, `k`="shape" and `L`="scale" in your notation.

Hence, `log[-log(1-F)]=k.log(x)-k.log(L)`, so, if you plotted the LHS against `log(x)` you would have slope `k` and y-intercept `-k.log(L)`. Thus, you can get the scale parameter `L` from `exp(-intercept/k)`.

I've put this in the code below and included it in the plot as orange crosses.

However, **the Weibull distribution is not a sensible fit to your data as it stands** - it makes more sense for x values from 0 to a few times `scale`. The only way I could make sense of fitting a Weibull distribution here was to apply it to `E-208.8` (the offset is a guess, based on your data and the need to keep it positive).

Code and output below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the parameters
E = np.array([208.9, 209.0, 209.2, 209.3, 209.6, 209.8, 209.9, 210])  # Electric breakdown strength 
E0 = 208.8               # bit of a guess!
E = E - E0
n = len( E )  # Sample size
i = np.arange(1, n + 1)  # Rank of observations

# Calculate the cumulative breakdown efficiency by the given formula
p = (i - 0.5) / (n + 0.25)

# variables
x_data = np.log(E)
y_data = np.log(-np.log(1 - p))

# Fit a linear regression to estimate the parameters of the Weibull distribution
slope, intercept = np.polyfit(x_data, y_data, 1)

# Calculate the shape parameter
shape = slope  
scale = np.exp( -intercept / shape )             # -k ln( lambda ) = intercept
print("Shape parameter:", slope)
print("Scale parameter:", scale)

# Represent the (scaled) fitted Weibull distribution
Weibull_CDF = 1.0 - np.exp( -( E / scale ) ** shape )
z = np.log( -np.log( 1.0 - Weibull_CDF ) )

# Generate points for the Weibull distribution
x = np.linspace(min(x_data), max(y_data), 100)
y = slope * x + intercept

# Plot
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o')
plt.plot(x_data, z, 'x', label="Weibull" )
plt.plot(x, y, label='Linear fit')
plt.xlabel('ln (E-E0)')
plt.ylabel('Probability of failure :ln(-ln(1 - p))')
plt.title('Weibull Plot')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Values:

```
Shape parameter: 1.3061117692466773
Scale parameter: 0.8009805959686129
```

Comment: @ lastchance Thank you.  but I would like to calculate the x-intercept where where the fitted line intersects with probability = 63.2% i.e., when ln(- ln(1-p)) = 0.  This x-intercept would be the charateristic field.

Comment: @ARINDAM DAS, yes, that point IS `Scale`. If you add back the offset that I used then the point will be E0+Scale=208.8+0.80098...=209.60098...